# Swift AVAssetExport Session operation stoped

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller, avassetexportsession

I am trying to export a .wav file from a video file extracted from a UIImagePickerController

> UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.mediaURL

Example url passed in to the function:

> **file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/PluginKitPlugin/BCE1C3A1-AA62-4D89-9487-05E19DB476A7/tmp/trim.3C31A33B-A99E-45B7-9101-5C225CFCFF2B.MOV**

I am able to sucesfully use this function to extract a m4a file but I cannot get it to work with a WAV file. The error I get running the code below is, **"Audio extraction as WAV failed with error: Operation Stopped"**

I do not know why I am getting **"Operation Stopped"** error on a wav file and not a m4a? An alternative I have tried is converting a m4a to wav after the fact and get the same error...

```
func extractAudioAsWAV(from mediaURL: URL) {
    
    let inputAsset = AVAsset(url: mediaURL)
    
    let outputFilePath = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory() + "out.wav")

    let audioAsset = inputAsset.tracks(withMediaType: .audio).first

    if let audioAsset = audioAsset {
        let composition = AVMutableComposition()
        let audioTrack = composition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: .audio, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)

        do {
            try audioTrack?.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRange(start: CMTime.zero, duration: inputAsset.duration), of: audioAsset, at: CMTime.zero)

            let exportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: composition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough)

            exportSession?.outputFileType = AVFileType.wav
            exportSession?.outputURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: outputFilePath.absoluteString)

            exportSession?.exportAsynchronously(completionHandler: {
                if exportSession?.status == .completed {
                    print("Audio extraction as WAV completed.")
                } else if let error = exportSession?.error {
                    print("Audio extraction as WAV failed with error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                }
            })
        } catch {
            print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        let videoURL = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.mediaURL] as? NSURL
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        extractAudioAsWAV(from: videoURL! as URL)

    }

func presentImagePicker() {
        imagePickerController.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        imagePickerController.delegate = self
        imagePickerController.mediaTypes = ["public.movie"]
        present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

The function **(extractAudioAsWAV)** above works by changing these lines of code for an m4a rather than a wav:

```
let outputFilePath = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory() + "out.m4a")
exportSession?.outputFileType = AVFileType.m4a
```